# Target a class if a pseudo class of another sibling is triggered

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have this *html:*

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="active-tab-name"> Inbox </div>
        <form class="search-box" method="get" action="#">

            <input type="text" name="search_query" />

            <button class="icon-search"></button>

        </form> 
</div>
```

I need to change the property of the button when my input is focused : on `input:focus` with css.
Here they are siblings and not nested. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the button is the following sibling of the input (as in your example code), you can use the direct sibling selector `+` :

```
input:focus + button{
    background:gold;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7X4qp/)**

If the button is a sibling of the input but not directly after the input, you can use the general sibling selector `~` :

```
input:focus ~ button{
    background:gold;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7X4qp/2/)**

Comment: Thanks man. It works awesomely. This is a generic doubt, is it possible to change properties of class that is not sibling but two level up, say parent's parent or something.?

Comment: @ynos1234 there is no parent selector in CSS, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector and you can't select previous siblings in CSS either.